# Laravel 5.7: When I dump $query (Builder obj.) it shows only global scope while local scope is applied but now shown. Is this intended behaviour?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

Without going to deep into details, **everything in my code works as expected** but the dump results aren't consistent with the logic.

So here within my repository class I dump a model.

```
$query = $this->model->customerWithCentralBillingChildren($customer);

dd($query);
```

The `customerWithCentralBillingChildren` is a local scope defined within `Model`.

```
public function scopeCustomerWithCentralBillingChildren($query, Customer $customer)
{
    $accdes = [CUT] // doesn't matter

    return $query->whereIn('accde', $accdes);
}
```

There's also a global scope that is applied via class that implements `Scope`. Located in `\App\Scopes`:

```
class SyncActive implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('sync_active', '=', true);
    }
}
```

My issue is that when I dump the `$query` it shows me only global scopes within array.

```
Builder {#858 ▼
  #query: Builder {#859 ▶}
  #model: Transaction {#676 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:13 [▶]
  #scopes: array:1 [▼
    "App\Scopes\SyncActive" => SyncActive {#677} <- global scope here, but why no local one?
  ]
  #removedScopes: []
}
```

Then only way for me to see that dumped query has also local scope is to dump:

```
dd($query->toSql());
```

Which gives:

```
"select * from `sync_transactions` where `accde` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `sync_active` = ?"
```

then I see local scope:

```
where `accde` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

as well as global scope:

```
`sync_active` = ?
```

**Is this intended behaviour? Why dumped `scopes` array item holds only global scope?**

Comment: This is the intended behavior. Global scopes are only applied when the query is executed/the SQL is generated. Otherwise, `withoutGlobalScopes()` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As per Laravel class documentation`, it is clearly mentioned the scoped attribute will contains the`Global Scopes`. No mentioned about the **local scope** anywhere.

```
protected array $scopes - Applied global scopes.    
protected array $removedScopes - Removed global scopes.
```

**Src:** https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html

Thought behind including global scope with query build, because of global scope applied automatically with each query that's why it specified with builder > attributes for the quick visibility.

While you'll have to call the local scope explicitly by adding yourself with each query.

Also with **Global Scopes** it has provided some extending features like extend, replace, remove, exclude etc. That attribute feature also could help to debug in such case.

***Note: It's just the personal thought based on facts provided with documentation. No where officially mentioned the caused behind this. But I'm sure this would be the initial thought***

Hopefully this could help you to clarify your concern.